# springdata mongo repository method to return specific document property list

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

using spring data for mongodb, how do I specify the return type of the repository method to include a particular property from the document?
Ex:

```java
@Document (collection = "foo")
class Foo {
   String id
   String name
   ... many more attributes
}
```

repository:

```java
interface FooRepository extends MongoRepository<Foo, String> {
   @Query { value = "{}", fields = "{'name' : 1}" }
   List<String> findAllNames()
}
```

Above `findAllNames` works as expected and fetches only name property from the document. However spring data returned object is a `string` representation of `Foo` object which has id and name properties with values and remaining attributes as null.
Instead of `Foo` objects, I need to fetch `List<String>` which represents names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, I used a custom interface to achieve this. Moved the findAllNames() method from Spring data repository interface to my custom interface

```java
interface FooRepositoryCustom {
    List<String> findAllNames()
}
interface FooRepository extends MongoRepository<Foo, String>, FooRepositoryCustom {
}

@Component
class FooRepositoryImpl implements FooRepositoryCustom {
   @Autowired
   MongoOperations mongoOperations;

  List<String> findAllNames() {
    //using mongoOperations create the query and execute. Return the property values from document
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, is there another way of doing this?